# @google-cloud/express-oauth2-handlers not detecting required keys: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL, GCP_PROJECT

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, handler

I am trying to use @google-cloud/express-oauth2-handlers package in Firebase function to authorize user to then query google APIs.

I provided the required keys in client_secret.json file in  root directory of my function/app as per npm instructions for this package, however it's still not detecting the required keys from the json file. Its throwing me below error.

```
firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'doppelganger-appl'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Error: Missing required keys: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL, GCP_PROJECT
at exports.Provider.Provider.required (/Users/<username>/my-doppelganger-app/functions/node_modules/nconf/lib/nconf/provider.js:364:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<username>/my-doppelganger-app/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/express-oauth2-handlers/config.js:53:7)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<username>/my-doppelganger- 
app/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/express-oauth2- 
handlers/tokenStorage.js:17:16)
```